# Examples of images causing buffer overflows?

Tags: virus, buffer-overflow

I remember reading a news article of an incident where a hacker was able to use an image to infect thousands (maybe millions?) of computers.

Can anyone provide links to such news articles? I couldn't find any on Google. I would like to show them to a friend.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typing a few most relevant keywords in a rectangular box, pressing enter, clicking on the first few links in search results and then reading the pages if they seem familiar.

Comment: "hahaha" very funny. Believe it or not, I could not find the relevant articles on Google. Maybe I'm having a brain fart and I'm not using the proper keywords. It happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recent TIFF exploit: http://www.darkreading.com/attacks-breaches/microsoft-warns-of-zero-day-attacks-expl/240163570

various older exploits (WMF, JPG, BMP): http://antivirus.about.com/od/virusdescriptions/a/wmfexploit_3.htm

other malformed image exploits (WMF, EMF, GIF, BMP): http://www.checkpoint.com/defense/advisories/public/announcement/ms-image-vulnerability.html